# Hardware AES support for .NET

Tags: .net, aes, hardware-acceleration

This is a simple one. Does .NET implementations of AES support hardware encryption/decryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find much information but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155774/6124) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8140221/6124) implies that [AesCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will make uses of [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) when available.

Comment: Although I can't see any official documentation to back this up so would take with a pinch of salt.

Comment: It astonishes me how many people do not know! I've contacted Microsoft and not even some of them know. I'm still waiting on a response from some MSDN officials on this one...