# Does the AES class in the .net framework use the AES instruction set

Tags: .net, cryptography

If not does anyone know how to use the AES instruction set using pInvoke , like is there any MSFT library that I can use for this purpose

Comment: @user2864740 [This one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a CNG (or AES-NI enabled instruction set) in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140221/how-to-use-a-cng-or-aes-ni-enabled-instruction-set-in-c-sharp)